# Why am I unable to delete a particular calendar event in Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, calendar

I have a recurring meeting invite in my Outlook 2007 calendar. A few days ago the meeting organiser sent out a cancellation for this week's particular occurrence - normally it would be removed from my calendar but for some reason this didn't happen.

I am now trying to delete the occurrence manually which I can usually do either by double clicking and choosing to open that occurrence's invite, or by right clicking and choosing Delete, then choosing the occurrence. This way it won't impact the overall recurring invite.

However since the cancellation, right clicking the invite does nothing - no pop up appears. If I double click it, I receive the following error:

[image: Cannot open this item. The operation failed. An object cannot be found.]

I've tried changing the *Current View* from *Day/Week/Month* to some of the list views such as *Events* but I can't seem to find the meeting. It seems from the error that the actual message itself has long been deleted but for some reason it still persists in the calendar UI.

How can I remove it?

Comment: what OS is that screenshot from? reminds me of Linux for some reason.

Comment: @studiohack - hehe, it's my work XP laptop but with some Linux resource customisation. The icons are from the Tango Desktop Project.

Comment: I suspected it was XP (because I know Outlook doesn't/can't run on Linux), but it looked so different.... :P

Comment: @studiohack If I'm forced to use a ten-year-old OS for my work, I should at least be able to make it look pretty! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't resolve this within the Outlook desktop client - I tried a huge number of approaches but the event wouldn't budge.

The solution was to log on to my account using **Outlook Web Access** and delete the event from there. I have no idea what the root cause was, but this was the only working solution in the end!

Comment: ++ Colleague of mine had same problem with Outlook 2010. He logged to the web interface and was able to delete the series easily, restarted Outlook and it worked perfectly!

Comment: deleting in web works !!

Answer (score 1):

I would try running

```
outlook /cleanreminders
```

There are other switches you can use to deal with various Outlook problems, check here for more details: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-outlook-2007-HP001218589.aspx

Other steps to resolve:

- Recreate OST file by disabling and then re-enabling cached mode
- Login to Outlook Web Access and delete the meeting from there

Comment: Thanks for the link Jon. Unfortunately running Outlook with the /cleanreminders switch didn't make any difference (I restarted Outlook again just in case that was required). I also tried a handful of other switches mentioned in the link that seemed to be related in some way, but none of them fixed the issue.

Comment: Are you running in cached mode or directly connected to Exchange ?  If cached, then try disabling and re-enabling this to recreate the OST file (this may take a while to sync if you have a large mailbox)

Comment: Unfortunately doing this didn't work. I also rebuilt the profile entirely and it still has the calendar event there that can't be removed. Perhaps this is on the Exchange side?

Comment: Could be.  Try logging on through Outlook Web Access and see if it is there

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete your appointment from this screen:

View -> Current View -> All Appointments

This is the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try logging out of Outlook and run it again.  You've reached the max deleted file count for your session and this will reset it.

Answer (score 1):

Go into your sent box that includes the original invite.  Open it up and hit decline.

Once this reply went through, it removed the item from my calendar.

Note I turned off my iPad and only connected to the account one way.  I'm not sure if this made a difference. I have but do not use Office Outlook 2013.